# Why is my AMD Topaz XT (m260) locking up my laptop?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, drivers, integrated-graphics, amd-graphics-card

I have a *Toshiba Satellite L-50* and I've installed Ubuntu 16.04 64 bit (kernel 4.4).
`lspci -nn` reports:

```
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Intel Corporation Haswell-ULT Integrated Graphics Controller [8086:0a16] (rev 0b)
...
09:00.0 Display controller [0380]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Topaz XT [Radeon R7 M260/M265 / M340/M360] [1002:6900] (rev ff)
```

Then when I execute `glxinfo` I can clearly see that I'm using the integrated *i5*; if I try to run `DRI_PRIME=1 glxinfo` the command waits for a while and then the system locks up (in some cases I've seen a *kernel panic*).

What shall I do to use my *AMD Topaz XT* when running *OpenGL/Vulkan*?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently it's the stock kernel version (4.4) of 16.04 which has an outdated *amdgpu* driver - upgrading the kernel to 4.7 made it work (albeit it's slower than my integrated i5).